# How to fix ftp 550 Socket I/O in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, ftp

I'm trying to ftp a file, I can log in, `/cd` successfully but it's giving I/O error after I try to `put` the file.

This is the problem I see after migrating to Windows 7.

```
ftp> put rtmmast.csv
200 PORT command successful.
550 I/O Error: Socket Closed
ftp> bye
```

Answer (score 0):

FTP [return code 550](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes) is "Requested action not taken. File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."

Ensure the FTP user account has write access to the folder/directory you are trying to `put` the file into (on the server).